Pre-render SSG Vue 3 with Vite and Options API
I've been looking for a plugin to pre-render some of the pages of my vue 3 app but so far I've been unlucky. I use Vite and the Options API, any suggestion?
I tried vite-ssg but it includes unhead using the Composition API and triggered a couple of errors when trying to use it.
Thanks!

composition API and options API can be used in the same project.  While I don't have first-hand knowledge of if Options API actually presents a problem specifically with vite-ssg, you should explain why you think it is so.  What errors are you getting? As it is now, you're asking for software recommendation which is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.

vitesse, Nuxt, or vite-ssg can help you achieve SSG. Options/Composition API are not really related to this topic. If those are errors and not warning, they can probably be fixed easily. Otherwise, you can also probably use some ChatGPT to convert Options API into Composition API. But don't expect a long term support for Options API haha.

Thank you both for your answers. My issue with Options API and and vite-ssg is that vite-ssg integrates the Composition API version of unhead... as you mentioned I can just convert into composition API. I'll also look into vitesse as well.
